Function whose Taylor Expansion has coefficients $\frac{1}{2^{2^n}-1}$
I have the following Taylor series: $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\limits \frac{1}{2^{2^n}-1} \cdot x^{n}$$
Can I find the function who has this Taylor series? The function needs to have this property: $$ f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2^{2^n}-1}$$
I tried the solution proposed for the series
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\limits n \cdot x^{n}$$
but it didn't work.

What do you mean by "the function", Do you mean the name? The expansion can be considered the definition of the function.

The function? Here, you have found it.

You probably are asking for a way to re-express the function; maybe as a closed form or integral?
